# How to put same character in multiple lines in android studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I have a file named "CMakeLists.txt" in android studio.
For example I have three lines in that -

```
line a
line b
line c
```

I want to put $ in beginning of all lines like -

```
$line a  
$line b  
$line c
```

Is there any keyboard shortcut or any other method so that I can make it without going to each line manually?

Answer (score 1):

Use 'column selection mode' by hit Alt+Shift+Insert (or from menu `Edit->Column Selection Mode`) then select first column of all lines and insert '$' character.

Another way is to replace all words 'line' whit '$line' if word 'line' is used only in the start of all lines of your text file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by selecting "line" keyword and press ctrl+F and replace it with "$line" or you can simply select all keyword and type "$line" it will replace all keyword as you want.